# Почему текст в табличке antdesign не переносится при сужении экрана?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ant-design

при сужении экрана в таблице antdesign текст не переносится на следующую строку, а заезжает под границу таблицы, `word-break: 'break-word;` не помогает(

Вот пример кода:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Chinese Score",
    dataIndex: "chinese",
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.chinese - b.chinese,
      multiple: 3
    }
  },
  {
    title: "Math Score",
    dataIndex: "math",
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.math - b.math,
      multiple: 2
    }
  },
  {
    title: "English Score",
    dataIndex: "english",
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.english - b.english,
      multiple: 1
    }
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    chinese: 98,
    math: 60,
    english: 70
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    chinese: 98,
    math: 66,
    english: 89
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    chinese: 98,
    math: 90,
    english: 70
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    chinese: 88,
    math: 99,
    english: 89
  }
];

function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter, extra) {
  console.log("params", pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    bordered
    tableLayout="fixed"
    dataSource={data}
    onChange={onChange}
  />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает, у меня работает, браузер хром

- Уберите свои стили "import "./index.css";"
- Попробуйте добавить
  `.ant-table-column-title { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }`
- Обратите внимание на версию antd (у меня 3.26.18)

Comment: спасибо) помогло